# ROOT cern in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, root-framework

I am starting to learn c++ and Root.
Want to do somethin easy like that:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "TF1.h"

int main() {
    TF1 *fa1 = new TF1("fa1", "sin(x)/x", 0, 10);
    fa1->Draw();
}
```

And...I have an error

> Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl
>   TF1::TF1(char const *,char const *,double,double)"
>   (??0TF1@@QEAA@PEBD0NN@Z)

( Visual Studio 2017 and root_v5.34)

I can do it from cmd but need to do from visual studio. Tell me please some solutions